# List all teams and the average raw scores for all members

Tags: sql, t-sql

My query is giving all the teams the exact same average player score. When each team would should have their own average score based on their team members.

```
select Teams.TeamName, avg(Bowler_Scores.RawScore) AvgPlyrScore
from Teams
join Bowlers on Teams.TeamID = Teams.TeamID
join Bowler_Scores on Bowlers.BowlerID = Bowler_Scores.BowlerID
group by Teams.TeamName;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your join should be

```
join Bowlers on Bowlers.TeamID = Teams.TeamID
```

Comment: Thanks. I feel inept for missing that.